# Which characters do I need to send from Android phone to show smiley characters on iPhones?

Tags: android

I am developing a chat application for Android which I want to use to send a message with smiley (Emoji) characters to iPhones. What characters do I need to send in text messages so that iPhones read those characters and automatically covert them into smileys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use Emoji charachters, that are part of the unicode standard since v6.0 like 'U+1F603' -> . Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Emoji_in_the_Unicode_standard

**Update**

This is the char:  So to test, copy it and send it.

**Update 2**

Here is a list (not complete) of basic smileys:

A complete list of smiley include in unicode v6.0 can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf).

When i send it to my Android, the smileys get automatically converted to the systems default smiley picture (or if set a user specific template). I guess, IOS behaves the same so you do not need to parse anything because this character is interpreted directly as a smiley.

On Android the smileys above become converted to the corresponding android smiley of the following picture:

[image]

Does that answer your question?

Comment: but what i need to send in text message so that in IOS it will coverts the chars to smiley.

Comment: The characters you can find on the link, e.g. send this:    I tried it on Android, it renders directly a OS specific smiley based on this character

Comment: Thanks Alex, It works for me too...
Do u know where i can get the Characters like  and respective images...?
So that it will be easy to work and map it for me...

Comment: OR do u have any solution that, how can i show the characters like  on android Textview/edittext. Currently My thinking is to parse the character came from iPhone, get those chars and place the images(smiley) from resources respective to those character. And as i know there are 722 characters....
do u have any solution, it will help me...

Comment: If you really have 722 smileys than its not standard because the unicode standard knows much lesser smiley as the list above shows.